# Why do some bones look like boxes and others like arrows?

Tags: interface, rigging

I've been looking at tutorials on how to rig a model and found this one.

Why does this guy's bones look like boxes while all the others look like triangular arrows? Is there a functional difference or just for ease of viewing? How do I enable/disable this display?

[image: Bones]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are the different shapes for an armature. Also the different controls for changing it. It is for you to decide what you want to use.

[image: armature display]

The one exception to this is that if you create your vertex weight from envelopes, you can view what will be affected with the envelope option. You must go into edit mode to see all details. More about it here:

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Rigging/Armatures/Editing/Properties

Answer (score 4):

The boxes could also be [Custom-Shapes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Rigging/Armatures/Visualization). The tab shown in the image is only availabe in *Pose or Object Mode*. From the layer panel in your screenshot I would guess that the custom shapes are at layer 11 (The one under layer 1 which is currently selected).

Here is an example of a rigify-rig:

[image]

Comment: I assumed the boxes were boxe with rendering mode set to wire. Can you tell the difference?

Comment: @Gunslinger At first sight I was pretty sure that the boxes are custom shapes because they are displaced. But you're right it could also be the wire frame display option, I changed the text to make clear that it is only another possibility.